# Connecting LED to iPhone's dock connector

Tags: led, iphone

Is it possible to connect a single LED to iPhone dock connector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [pinout](http://pinouts.ru/PortableDevices/ipod_pinout.shtml) there appears to be 3.3V output available at pin 18, so for a typical 5mm red LED of Vf 1.8V, with 20mA through it:

(3.3 - 1.8) / 0.02 = 75\$\Omega \$

So 75 ohm from pin 18 to LED anode, LED cathode to one of the ground pins (e.g. pin 15)